# how to retrieve data from app of In App purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My IN App Purchase application is running fine in iPhone but when i purchase the item through In App purchase that time i get the message that you have successfully purchase but download hasn't done. So I want to  know that by using which code I will download the item and where it will be use to store.

Comment: can you explain it little better...? I don't think so anyone can get anything out of your question...

Comment: Are you saying that when you make an in app purchase it doesn't download it?

Answer (score 0):

In app purchases can't actually download anything by themselves. When the user completes the purchase, your application is notified and then you can either initiate the download from a remote server, or activate code or functionality already in your application.

More information here:  [In App Purchase Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Also, please don't add m as a tag.